# Play vimeo domain locked videos in mobile app

Tags: android, cordova, video, vimeo

I am developing a ios/android mobile application using phonegap/cordova. The problem is that i want to play a domain locked vimeo video inside it. Currently, I am using iframe to launch the video but I am getting 403 (Forbidden) error.
Is there any way to launch the domain locked vimeo videos inside phonegap/cordova app?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way for a domain-locked video to indicate that it should be playable in a mobile app.

One option is to use direct video file access instead of the embed player. Video file access is available to PRO and Business users.